# Updating view or table definition in BigQuery sandbox causes billing error

Tags: google-bigquery

Trying to update a table or a view, even just setting its Description, in BigQuery Sandbox, produces this error message:

> **Unexpected error**
>
> Billing has not been enabled for this project. Enable billing at https://console.cloud.google.com/billing. Table expiration time must be less than 60 days while in sandbox mode.

This also happens when trying to update the table expiration time (to < 60 days, trying to solve the problem). The only workaround I've found is to save a copy of the view or table under a different name, remove the original, save the copy to the original name, then delete the copy. (Tedious, and doesn't work for metadata like Description.)

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: I know two ways to do this. There is the way that you mention, and the other way is to enable the billing. After enabling the billing you can still use the free tier, but you can generate charges. To manage BigQuery quotas, you can set up [cost controls](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/custom-quotas).

Comment: Thanks!  I'll look into cost controls. I just didn't see anything in the documentation that says "unless billing is turned on, you can't update persistent objects". Seems like a pointless restriction--it's not like saving a view description is an expensive operation. And it doesn't seem to be in the docs.

Comment: It shouldn’t be happening, as you mentioned. I am giving you a possible workaround that you can use. Additionally turning the billing it might be something that you maybe can get charged, but you unlock a lot more features in BigQuery. And controlling the cost can lead you to have the same plan as you have.